# Add to collection existing identificator

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have Customer with Orders collection. I have some orders identificators which I need to add to new Customer instance like this:

```
var customer = new Customer();
customer.Orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 1 });
customer.Orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 2 });
customer.Orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 3 });
```

Is it possible without retrieveing approapriate Order instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you must do it in correct order. The simplest way is:

```
var order1 = new Order { Id = 1 };
context.Orders.Attach(order1); // Now context knows the order and it tracks it as unchanged

var customer = new Customer();
context.Customers.AddObject(customer); // Now context knows the customer and it tracks it as a new

customer.Orders.Add(order1); // Now context knows about new relation between new customer and existing order
```

If you do it as you showed in your example you will call:

```
context.Customers.AddObject(customer);
```

and context will track customer and all related orders as a new one so you will have to manually change state of all orders to unchanged to avoid duplicate inserts:

```
foreach (var order in customer.Orders)
{
   if (order.Id != 0)
   {
       context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(order, EntityState.Unchagned);
   }
}
```